# Validation with img upload with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to insert data to the database and at the same time uploading an image to the path. It seems the problem is with the validation, but I can't see where is the error. I've been stuck for two days trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code for the upload:

```
 protected function store(Request $request)
  {

      $nameFile = null;


      if ($request->hasFile('image')) {


          $name = uniqid(date('HisYmd'));


          $extension = $request->image->extension();


          $nameFile = "{$name}.{$extension}";


          $upload = $request->image->storeAs('categories', $nameFile);

          return $namefile;

      }
  }
```

Here's the create function:

```
protected function create(array $data){
     $image = $this->store();
     return Bottleneck::create([
        'setor_id' => $data['setor_id'],
        'mes' => $data['mes'],
        'ano' => $data['ano'],
        'andon' => $data['andon'],
        'conteudo' => $data['coteudo'],
        'atividade_total' => $data['atividade_total'],
        'image' => $image
     ]);
 }
```

Here's the validation:

```
 protected function validator(array $data){
     return Validator::make($data , [
        'setor_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'exists:setor_linha,id'],
        'mes' => ['required', 'integer'],
        'ano' => ['required', 'integer'],
        'andon' => ['required', 'string'],
        'conteudo' => ['required', 'string'],
        'atividade_total' => ['required', 'string'],
        'image' => ['image'],
     ]);
 }
```

The save function:

```
public function save(Request $request){
     $validation = $this->validator($request->all());
     if($validation->fails()){
         Session::flash('message', 'Error');
        return redirect()->route('bottleneck');
     }else{
        $bottleneck = $this->create($request->all());
        Session::flash('message', 'Success');
        return redirect()->route('bottleneck');
     }
 }
```

And here's my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route("create.bottleneck")}}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="setor_id" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
                            {{__('Production Line')}}
                        </label>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <select id="setor_id" name="setor_id" class="form-control " required>
                                <option>{{__('Select Value')}}</option>
                                    @forEach($line as $data)
                                        <option value={{$data->id}}>{{$data->name}}</option>
                                    @endforEach
                            </select>

                            @if($errors->has('setor_id'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>
                                        {{$errors->first('setor_id')}}
                                    </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="mes" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{__('Month')}}</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="number" name="mes" class="form-control">


                            @if($errors->has('mes'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>
                                        {{$errors->first('mes')}}
                                    </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="ano" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{__('Year')}}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="number" name="ano" class="form-control" required>

                            @if($errors->has('ano'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>
                                        {{$errors->first('ano')}}
                                    </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="andon" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{__('Andon')}}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <textarea name="andon" class="form-control" required></textarea>

                            @if($errors->has('andon'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>
                                        {{$errors->first('andon')}}
                                    </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="conteudo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{__('Content')}}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <textarea name="conteudo" class="form-control" required></textarea>

                            @if($errors->has('conteudo'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>
                                        {{$errors->first('conteudo')}}
                                    </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="atividade_total" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{__('Total Work')}}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" name="atividade_total" required>

                            @if($errors->has('atividade_total'))
                                <span class="invalida-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>
                                        {{$errors->first('atividade_total')}}
                                    </strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{__('Image')}}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">

                            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                                    <ul>
                                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                {{__('Save')}}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: You have to use `enctype="multipart/form-data" ` in your form tag when you are dealing with input file types. dump the requests in controller and check the requests.

Comment: check this tutorial out, https://laraveldaily.com/upload-multiple-files-laravel-5-4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form needs to have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to upload images.